# Is my mortgage more likely to be sold if I pre-pay principal?

Tags: united-states, mortgage

I've had a mortgage since 2011, and it's already been sold twice. I pay about 10% additional principal each month. Is this a practice that mortgage holders might find undesirable and make it more likely that they sell my note to someone else? I'm going to pre-pay either way, I'm curious to see if someone has insight on the matter.

Comment: Why do you care?  I don't mean to be flippant - I'm just curious, what effect does the collateralization of your mortgage have on you?

Comment: Collateralization might not have a big effect, but servicing changes do have a big effect.

Comment: I'm just wondering if it's a fact of life that I'll need to fill out a bunch of paperwork every year on a mortgage I already have. But like I said, it's not really going to affect my behavior.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways that mortgages are sold:

The loan is collateralized and sold to investors. This allows the bank to free up money for more loans. Of course sometime the loan may be treated like in the game of hot potato nobody want s to be holding a shaky loan when it goes into default.

The second way that a loan is sold is through the servicing of the loan. This is the company or bank that collects your monthly payments, and handles the disbursement of escrow funds. Some banks lenders never sell servicing, others never do the servicing themselves. Once the servicing is sold the first time there is no telling how many times it will be sold.

The servicing of the loan is separate from the collateralization of the loan.

When you applied for the loan you should have been given a [Servicing Disclosure Statement](http://portal.hud.gov/hudportal/HUD?src=/program_offices/housing/ramh/res/sc2sectg)

> Servicing Disclosure Statement. RESPA requires the lender or mortgage
>   broker to tell you in writing, when you apply for a loan or within the
>   next three business days, whether it expects that someone else will be
>   servicing your loan (collecting your payments).

The [language is set by the US government](http://www.fdic.gov/regulations/laws/rules/6500-3100.html):

> [We may assign, sell, or transfer the servicing of your loan while the
>   loan is outstanding.] [or] [We do not service mortgage loans of the
>   type for which you applied. We intend to assign, sell, or transfer the
>   servicing of your mortgage loan before the first payment is due.] [or]
>   [The loan for which you have applied will be serviced at this
>   financial institution and we do not intend to sell, transfer, or
>   assign the servicing of the loan.] [INSTRUCTIONS TO PREPARER: Insert
>   the date and select the appropriate language under "Servicing Transfer
>   Information." The model format may be annotated with further
>   information that clarifies or enhances the model language.]

Answer (score 3):

It's not unusual/undesirable.

If *everyone* prepaid their mortgage, banks would not like this, but we're in no danger of that :). Also, the amount you are pre-paying is not so significant as to make them pay special attention. In many cases when a borrower pre-pays, they will not continue to do so over the life of the loan since it's so easy to stop at any time, and the extra payments are voluntary.

Depending on who originated the mortgate, it might be sold even more often than in your case. It's no longer commonplace for a bank to hold a mortgage to maturity, now that banks and other institutions have separated the origination of the loan from its servicing.

It's likely that your mortgage was bundled with others through a process called securitization, and will be bought/sold based on the bank's need for liquitity or to balance out the maturity of its assets and liabilities (whether they need more cash now versus later), or based on the types of ways your bank has decided that it wants to make money versus farming out other types of business to others.

What would substantially change the value of your mortgage to a bank is if it were performing (ie you are paying on time) but then became non-performing (ie you fall behind in your payments). It's also possible that if you have a very small mortgage or principal balance, that there is very little risk to the bank, and little difference between the present and future values of your loan, but banks don't typically make these types of transactions based on the characteristics of an individual loan.

Answer (score 1):

In a process called collateralization, your mortgage is combined with others to form a security that other can invest in. When done right, this process provides liquidity, more money to be lent for more loans. When done wrong, bad things happen.

My mortgage happens to be held by the issuing bank. Yours was sold into such a pool of mortgages. One effect of this is the reselling of the servicing of the loan. I've had other mortgages that were sold every year, but I never paid ahead. With this bank, I'm on my fifth refinance, but the bank keeps the loan in house no matter what. I don't know if there's any correlation, it depends on the originating bank, in my opinion.